# How to generate EDMX file from MSBuild?

Tags: entity-framework

I need to update EF model form database during MSBuild. How could it be accomplished?
I tried EdmGen2. It generates edmx file for previous versions of Entity Framework.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use the updated edmgen2 available here: https://github.com/cincuranet/EdmGen2

Comment: I use version you've recomended. Then **edmx** file is included into the project, custom tool was ran. All tables and views objects are generated successfully but stored procedures are missing.

Comment: How are **.tt** files related to the code generation?

Comment: .tt files generate code based on a template and the EDMX file, and is used by the GUI EF Tools. I think you can invoke during build also.

Comment: How could i only get store procedures. I dont want any table or views. Only store procedures.